# Injection of Request Scope objects into MVC ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc, actionfilterattribute

I have a shopping cart service `IShoppingCartService` that is defined with Ninject as being `InRequestScope`

```
  this.Bind<IShoppingCartService>().To<ShoppingCartService>().InRequestScope();
```

It loads the user's shopping cart and caches it internally. Once the request is over then the service object goes away.

I needed to access the shopping cart within an `ActionFilter` so I used the `[Inject]` attribute.

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IShoppingCartService ShoppingCartService
    {
       get; set;
    }
}
```

I can then use it in the action filter like this

```
 public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
 {
       var cart = ShoppingCartService.ShoppingCart;
       ...
 }
```

Now for the weird part. This has been working just fine for a year or more - and then suddenly (after recently upgrading Ninject and MVC) I notice that the shopping cart is being cached (i.e. not `InRequestScope`).

On further research I see that ActionFilters are singletons (I verified this given that the constructor was only ever called once). So once an instance of the shopping cart is loaded it is locked in forever.

So my question is - how on earth did this ever work? Did something recently change in Ninject or MVC that could have allowed this to work before.

My fix right now is to do the following :

```
 public IShoppingCartService ShoppingCartService
 {
     get
     {
         var scs = (IShoppingCartService) DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IShoppingCartService));
         return scs;
     }
 }
```

I'm really confused though as to how this ever could have worked - and it definitely did. What should I have done instead?

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe* while the filter attribute was only instantiated once, the property was `[Injected]`-ed every time the page as hit. But let's look forward :)

In 2010 a "new" way was implemented in `Ninject.MVCx` (x =3, 5,..) on how to inject stuff into action filters. It doesn't need to rely on attributes and it supports constructor injection. Here's how it looks like:

(*Fair warning*: i don't usually do asp.net development and i didn't get to try out if the following does change anything about the lifecycle of the `IActionFilter`, so you'll have to try it out yourself. If you do, please provide feedback)

```
public class MyActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService;

    public MyActionFilter(IShoppingCartService shoppingCartService)
    {
        this.shoppingCartService = shoppingCartService;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var cart = ShoppingCartService.ShoppingCart;
        ...
    }
}
```

The filter then needs to be bound by a special method `BindFilter`:

```
this.BindFilter<MyActionFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
    .WhenControllerTypeIs<YourController>();
```

which would apply it to all the actions of `YourController`.

There's also other targets you can apply the filter to, by using:

```
// Is applied to all actions of controllers which have the FooAttribute
this.BindFilter<MyActionFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
    .WhenControllerHas<FooAttribute>();

// Is applied to all actions which have the FooAttribute
this.BindFilter<MyActionFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
    .WhenActionHas<FooAttribute>();

// Is applied to all actions named Index
this.BindFilter<MyActionFilter>(FilterScope.Action, 0)
    .When((controllerContext,  actionDescriptor) =>
        actionDescriptor.ActionName == "Index");
```

There's some more info on that which can be found in a great article by [Remo Gloor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448580/remo-gloor): [Official Ninject MVC extension gets support for MVC3](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2010/11/13/official-ninject-mvc-extension-gets-support-for-mvc3/) (chapter *Dependency Injection for filters*)